# How to use Normal to recover translated points

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, geometry

[image]

I'm working through a coding exercise to program a matrix of [Lissajour Curves](https://github.com/CodingTrain/website/blob/master/CodingChallenges/CC_116_Lissajous/Processing/CC_116_Lissajous/CC_116_Lissajous.pde) in Mathematica but have encountered an obstacle when trying to recover the translated `Point` to then do further processing on them (as seen through the link). I've encountered problems trying to recovering the updated coordinates of translated points using `Normal` [before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175963/how-to-retrieve-updated-point-coordinates-that-have-been-scaled-or-translated?noredirect=1&lq=1). In this case I've gone so far as to try to rebuild that solution in my current notebook to no avail. It seems like there should be some application of `Normal` to `Graphics[graphicsdata]` that would generate the updated point coordinates in a list. I'm not sure what I'm missing about how `Normal` works but it would be useful to understand it as I try to advance my Mathematica program complexity.

```
angle = Drop[Range[0,Pi 2,(2 Pi)/20],-1];
cols = 5;
rows = 3;
radius = .45;

functionXY[anglevar_]:= {radius * Cos[anglevar],radius * Sin[anglevar]}

translatevectors = Flatten[{Table[{x,0},{x,cols}],Table[{0,-y},{y,rows}]},1];
points = Point /@ functionXY /@ angle;
graphicsdata = Table[Translate[#, translatevectors[[n]]] &/@ points,{n,Length@translatevectors}];
Graphics[graphicsdata]
```

---

**Updated Dec 29 2018**

I just thought it would be helpful to post the updated code here using the suggestions below should others find themselves in the postion of `Normal` not recovering translated coordinates as expected. In this case it is probably better to use `TranslationTransform` in the first place as now `graphicsdata` returns exactly the updated point's new coordinates that can be further post-processed.

```
elementaryPoints = functionXY /@ angle;
graphicsdata = Table[TranslationTransform[translatevectors[[n]]]@# &/@ elementaryPoints,{n,Length@translatevectors}];
Table[Point /@ graphicsdata[[n]],{n, Length@translatevectors}] // Graphics
```

[image]

Comment: maybe `normal = # /. Translate[(prim : Alternatives[Point, Line, Circle])[x_, y___], 
      t_] :> prim[TranslationTransform[t]@x, y] &;
normal@Graphics[graphicsdata]`?
`

Comment: I'm new to being able to close questions with one vote, so if you think this shouldn't be closed, just let me know.

Comment: I'd suggest not closing it. I rarely see the overlap and it has two votes now anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the linked q/a, the section Properties and Relations in [`Scale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale.html), [`Translate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html) and [`GeometricTransformation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation.html) says:

> ***When possible***, Normal *will transform the coordinates explicitly.*

When `Normal` does not work, you can post-process the translated primitives to regular primitives with translated coordinates:

```
normal = # /. Translate[Point[x_], t_] :> Point[TranslationTransform[t]@x] &;
coords = Cases[normal@Graphics[graphicsdata], Point[x_] :> x, ∞];

Show[ListPlot[coords, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[7], Opacity[.7, Red]]], 
 Graphics[graphicsdata]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks; that all checks out wonderfully. I, of course, read that in the docs, but was puzzled as to what the exact conditions were when it is possible. Perhaps I should be rewriting this part of the code to use `TranslationTransform` instead of `Translate`?