# Methods to retrieve edges from Cuboid and other complex graphic primitive

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, geometry

I am trying to get the edges as `Line`s from an `ArrayPlot` to do further analysis on such as remove edges depending on location or change their visual properties based on its location. I was unable to recover the actual coordinates of the `Cuboid` with `Normal` or the method mentioned in [my previous post on a similar though slightly less complex example with `Point`s.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188533/how-to-use-normal-to-recover-translated-points)

```
g = ArrayPlot3D[ConstantArray[1, {4, 4, 4}]]
```

[image]

I was able to dig into the expression and get some way toward the look I want but I'm not sure what the next steps in manipulating it are to get a list of `Line`s with the correct 3D coordinates.

```
gg = g[[1, 2, 1]]
Translate[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Directive[GrayLevel[0.2]]], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}]},
{{0, -4, -4}, {1, -4, -4}, {2, -4, -4}, {3, -4, -4}, {0, -3, -4}, {1, -3, -4}, {2, -3, -4}, {3, -3, -4}, {0, -2, -4}, {1, -2, -4}, {2, -2, -4}, {3, -2, -4}, {0, -1, -4}, {1, -1, -4}, {2, -1, -4}, {3, -1, -4}, {0, -4, -3}, {1, -4, -3}, {2, -4, -3}, {3, -4, -3}, {0, -3, -3}, {1, -3, -3}, {2, -3, -3}, {3, -3, -3}, {0, -2, -3}, {1, -2, -3}, {2, -2, -3}, {3, -2, -3}, {0, -1, -3}, {1, -1, -3}, {2, -1, -3}, {3, -1, -3}, {0, -4, -2}, {1, -4, -2}, {2, -4, -2}, {3, -4, -2}, {0, -3, -2}, {1, -3, -2}, {2, -3, -2}, {3, -3, -2}, {0, -2, -2}, {1, -2, -2}, {2, -2, -2}, {3, -2, -2}, {0, -1, -2}, {1, -1, -2}, {2, -1, -2}, {3, -1, -2}, {0, -4, -1}, {1, -4, -1}, {2, -4, -1}, {3, -4, -1}, {0, -3, -1}, {1, -3, -1}, {2, -3, -1}, {3, -3, -1}, {0, -2, -1}, {1, -2, -1}, {2, -2, -1}, {3, -2, -1}, {0, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {2, -1, -1}, {3, -1, -1}}
]
Graphics3D@gg
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract lines (and other graphics primitives, like points for vertices, and polygons for faces) using [`MeshPrimitives`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshPrimitives.html).
[`ArrayPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot3D.html) seems to use a convoluted specification consisting of translating a single [`Cuboid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cuboid.html) around, but in any case the following seems to work:

```
ArrayPlot3D[ConstantArray[1, {4, 4, 4}]] /. 
 Cuboid[a_] :> MeshPrimitives[Cuboid[a], 1]
```